# Firefox, touch events and "smooth" scroll behaviour – results in no scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, scroll, touch-event

I'm at a loss as to what is going on here.

Please refer to the CodePen: https://codepen.io/ilmiont/pen/jJjgPw?editors=1111

Swiping with a touchscreen should smoothly transition the screens up and down, using the "smooth" scroll behaviour.

This does work exactly as intended with Chrome.

Firefox... just doesn't scroll. Yet the touch events are being fired, and "Next" / "Previous" is being logged to the console. But the `scrollIntoView(...)` call does nothing when invoked with `{behavior: "smooth"}`.

If you click the button, the scroll behaviour is changed to `auto` (no smooth scrolling)... and this works without any issues in Firefox.

What have I missed? Why  is Firefox not scrolling at all when `smooth` scroll behaviour is used, even though it seems the swipes are being detected correctly?

A further oddity: the demo doesn't work in Chrome in CodePen either. Copy the HTML/CSS/JS into a new document (right-click CodePen viewer, "view frame source") and run directly in the browser, and it works exactly as intended, with smooth scrolling within the pages.

I think I must have missed something, and the CodePen issues in Chrome are interesting, but I just can't see what right now.

Chrome... just works... except in CodePen.

Firefox... everything looks like it *should* work, but the scrolling never occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This has taken me far too long to figure out, but here's the solution which finally works:

**Use passive event listeners!**

In the original pen, I was doing `{passive: false}` and then calling `preventDefault(...)` on the `touchstart` and `touchmove` events.

It turns out, that this isn't necessary to achieve the desired effect.

Using the passive listeners results in everything working as intended in Firefox.

I still consider the original behaviour is odd; further investigation revealed there seems to be a timing issue in Firefox. In the `swipe(...)` method, adding a 250ms timeout to the `dispatchEvent(...)` call results in everything working as intended also – it seems as though the touch handlers can continue to block/throttle scroll events past when they should have been removed.

Will keep investigating but I have a solution for now.

(**Edit** – forgot to mention, when using passive listeners, also set `touch-action: none` on the target.)